# Creating my own array.prototype.map method. How can I access the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

So I am trying to create a method that mimic exactly what the `Array.prototype.map()` method does and there is a lot I am confused about. 
The main problem I suppose comes down to its syntax. I know there are many different ways to utilitize the `map` method for instance:

example 1:

let say I have an array of objects -

```
var movieList = [
   {"Title" : "Inception",
   "Awards" : "4 oscars",
   "Language" : "English",
   "imdbRating" : "8.8"
   },

   {"Title" : "Inception2",
   "Awards" : "44 oscars",
   "Language" : "English and Spanish",
   "imdbRating" : "9.8"
   },

   {"Title" : "Interstellar",
   "Awards" : "10 oscars",
   "Language" : "English",
   "imdbRating" : "9.5"
   }
];
```

Lets say I want to make a function that returns a list of objects that contains only the title of the movie and its imdbRating. In this case, I can use the `map()` method:

```
let newList = movieList.map( (current) ({'title': current['Title'],     
               'rating': current['imdbRating'] }) );
```

the above line of code satisfies what i need to achieve my objective using the map method. However, the syntax can be different for other cases

example 2:

```
let s = [1, 2, 3, 4];

let s2 = s.map( function(item) {
   return item*2;
});
```

using the map function s2 will return an array that has for each element double the value of each element in the s array. 
Now, going back to the theme of this post, the problem I am working on gave me this outline to start with:

```
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) {
   let newArray = [];
```

I understand that when an array calls on the `myMap` method, it is inserting 2 arguments, the array and a function. But I cannot wrap my head around how I can concretely assign the value of each callback function on the element to the `newArray` in the `myMap` method. Especially because I do not know how to access the original array.

One of my attempts that I know is ridiculous because I do not know how I can access the length of the array as well as the array itself which calls on the `myMap` method-

```
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) {
   let newArray = [];
   let x = this.length();
   for(let i=0; i<x; i++){
       let counter = callback();
       newArray.push(counter);
   }
   return newArray;
};
```

the way I've understood the `map()` method thus far, is it takes 3 arguments, an array, a function, and the element that will be put thru the function and I do not know the syntax well enough to iterate over the array that calls on the `map` method and nowhere in my course have I been taught how to do this and I have not found any online resource either that offers a solution to this problem.

Comment: what is `Array.myMap` supposed to be? and why would it have a function called length? seems you wanted `this.length` - or you can study a [Array#map polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill)

Comment: yeah i tried this.length and it wouldn't work. that was just my last-ditch attempt at trying to figure the length of the array that calls on the method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`length` is not a method - it's just a property. And you need to pass `this[i]` to the `callback` for the correct output.

```js
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) {
  let newArray = [];
  let x = this.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    let counter = callback(this[i]);
    newArray.push(counter);
  }
  return newArray;
};

let arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr = arr.myMap(e => e * 2);
console.log(arr);
```

Please note it's quite bad practice to mutate the prototype methods - and especially creating a new one when an identical method exists. (`map` has all the functionality of `myMap` plus more).

Comment: yes it works. thank u so much. i completely forgot about the this.property syntax... i was stressing over so much about the function and all the components that make up the map method that i completely overlooked the simplest syntax that solved my problem.

Comment: *map* doesn't visit non–existent or deleted properties within the index range 0 to initial length - 1, but this version will. There needs to be a *hasOwnProperty* test before processing values.

Comment: @RobG What do you mean? Just an `if` statement before the call-back? And if so, what would the value for that item be? Would a `filter` be required?

Comment: Missing items in the initial array are also missing from the map, they aren't visited at all. E.g. `[0,,,3].map(fn)` only visits elements 0 and 3 since 1 and 2 don't exist, so they are also missing in the result. So you need to test if the element exists (say `this.hasOwnProperty(i)`) and then assign to the index rather than using *push*.

Comment: Looks pretty good but you also need to take care about the `i` (index), so calling the callback should look like: `callback(this[i], i, this)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is simplified version of the actual [`map` Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill). You need to get the `length` using `this.length`. And pass the current item in loop, it's index, and the array itself as a parameter to `callback`

```js
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback, thisArg) {
  const newArray = [];
  const length = this.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let value = callback(this[i], i, this); // call with proper arguments
    newArray.push(value);
  }

  return newArray;
};

const arr = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(arr.myMap(a => a * 2))
```

Note: `map` method also takes a `thisArg` as parameter. If you want to use that, you need to [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) the `callback` with `thisArg` as `this`

```
callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73777676/), but correctly preserves empty items.

```
Array.prototype.map = function (callback, thisArg) { 
    let arr = [];
    const len = this.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in this) arr.push(callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this));
        else arr.length++;
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Comment: I like this, but would it not be more efficient just to do `new Array(this.length)` up front instead?

Comment: You mean instead of `let arr = [];` ?

Comment: And incrementing the length every iteration, yes.

Comment: [Something like this](https://tio.run/##bY/LTgMxDEXXyVd4mdAS8RCrUCS@AyEUQqY1BGfkyYAq1G8f7AF2rPzIufc6r@kjTZlx7OfUXsqy3DOnYxi59daPYwlP72mEHQwz5Y6NwOVU63PKbx6@rMmNpg6JWRAqn7CqXT/gFGqhfT/4aM3QGFwtHVCoiyjlViW/hMybzWpmcACHgARq4GVhBHvAR5H9pQZtHM21bldKXreAP71mnazh0mcmTYj2FK39/8YbodX9Wt0v40q1WkJte6fH6b9dht0dZDiDK@/jsnwD "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: Seems better quite frankly. I can't think of a use case in which initializing the array length would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where you can learn about javascript map function more: 
    https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Implementing map method is actually quite easier than you think. Here is a really simple example that would do exactly what the map method do from    https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp:

```
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) {
    arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        arr.push(callback(this[i], i, this));
    return arr;
};

//tests
var numbers2 = [1, 4, 9];

var squareRoot = numbers2.myMap(function(num) {
    return Math.sqrt(num);
});

console.log(squareRoot); // [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

So, the map method simply returns an array by whose values map to the original array's values by running a specified function given as an argument on each of the values.

**Note:** The method skips the optional parameter of the original map function which specifies what will be the `this` value

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of your `myMap` function.

A part of imitating these methods that may confuse people is how the `this` keyword works in javascript. Here is an [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions) article.

```
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback, thisArg) {
  let newArray = [];
  let x = this.length;
  for(let i=0; i<x; i++){
    let counter = callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
    newArray.push(counter);
  }
  return newArray;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Array.prototype.mappy = function (callback, thisArg) { 
    let newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (i in this) newArray.push(callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this));
        else newArray.push(undefined);
    }
    return newArray;
};
```

Comment: What is the point of `i in this`? Also, please take the time to format your post properly.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance The point of `i in this` is to handle empty array indexes. For example, If you try to make an arithmetic operation with an empty array index, is returns `NaN`, instead of `undefined`.

Comment: @ManosKaparos True, but then pushing `undefined` doesn't really make sense here as the real `map` preserves empty items. Probably the real way to do it is to create the new array with the original length, then copy only when `i in this` is `true`.

Comment: I completely agree in the first statement. Since `NaN` can represent an undefined or an unpresentable value, hence an empty array index. The thing is that, in this case, the original prototype map method returns neither `undefined` nor 'NaN' but an empty element instead. Regarding the creation of the new array, I believe that it is situational since you can no longer compare old array with the new one, based on index values and length. Check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74700247

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the spread operator and do something like this:

```
Map.prototype.slice = function(start, end) {
    return new Map([...this].slice(start, end));
};
```

And in use:

```
const testMap = new Map([["a", 1], ['b', 2], ["c", 3], ["d", 4], ["e", 5]]);
console.log(testMap); // Map(5) { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5 }
console.log(testMap.slice(0, 2)); // Map(2) { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 }
```

You can definitely build upon this since this still has the caveats of `Array.prototype.slice()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `forEach` if you don't want to use a `for loop`

```js
Array.prototype.myMap = function (callback) {
  let newArr = [];
  this.forEach((item) => {
    let elem = callback(item);
    newArr.push(elem);
  });
  return newArr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom map function in javascript

```
 Array.prototype.myMap = function (cb){
    let temp =[];
    for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
    temp.push(cb(this[i], i, this))
    }
    return temp;
    };
```

In this custom function callback cb having three arguments is current element, index and actual array.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
//using myMap
arr.myMap((num)=>num)
```

Answer (score 0):

my proposition on how to doing with recursive way with typescript

```
Array.prototype.customMap = function customMap<T>(
  callback: (element: T, index: number, array: T[], self?: T[]) => T
): T[] {
  if (this.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }
  return (([index, result]) => {
    return [
      callback(
        this[this.length - 1 - index],
        this.length - 1 - index,
        this,
        this
      ),
      ...result,
    ];
  })(mapWithSize<T>(this.slice(1), callback));
};


function mapWithSize<T>(
  sequence: T[],
  callback: (element: T, index: number, array: T[], self?: T[]) => T
): [number, T[]] {
  return [sequence.length, sequence.customMap(callback)];
}
```