# how to create own map function in typescript

Tags: arrays, reactjs

We are creating our own map function. Sometimes in an interview, Interviewer asked for the implementation of the map function. How it behaves internally using a callback.

````
    Map Polyfill
 
// @ts-ignore
// eslint-disable-next-line no-extend-native
Array.prototype.myOwnMap = function myOwnMap(
  callback: (inputElement: number, index?: number, array?: number[]) => number
): number[] {
  const outputArr: number[] = [];
  for (let iterator = 0; iterator < inputElements.length; iterator++) {
    outputArr.push(callback(inputElements[iterator], iterator, inputElements));
  }
  return outputArr;
};

// @ts-ignore
const outputElements: number[] = inputElements.myOwnMap(
  (element: number, index: number, array: number[]) => {
    return element + index * 2;
  }
);
console.log("We are expecting result is [ 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16 ]", outputElements);```
````

Comment: is it best practice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating my own array.prototype.map method. How can I access the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660756/creating-my-own-array-prototype-map-method-how-can-i-access-the-array)

Answer (score 0):

In the same way, I created polyfill for filter functions as well.

```
/**
 *   Filter polyfill
 */

//@ts-ignore
// eslint-disable-next-line no-extend-native
Array.prototype.myOwnFilter = function myOwnFilter(
  callback: (value: number, index?: number, array?: number[]) => number
): number[] {
  const newArrayElements: number[] = [];
  for (let iterator = 0; iterator < inputElements.length; iterator++) {
    if (!!callback(inputElements[iterator], iterator, inputElements))
      newArrayElements.push(inputElements[iterator]);
  }
  return newArrayElements;
};

// @ts-ignore
const outputElement: number[] = inputElements.myOwnFilter(
  (value: number) => value % 2 === 0
);

console.log("We are expecting array [2,4,6]", outputElement);
```